# Drupal Don't apply sort criteria by default

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I added sort criteria by price to my catalog view, and in the sort criteria I have only to option to use by default one of them - Ascending or Descending. But I don't want to use any sorting by price by default in catalog, I would like to apply it (one of the option Ascending or Descending) only after user chose an option and pressed button 'Apply' on the sort form. Is there any opportunity to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a default sort criteria (post date or something) move it to the first position. I think you don't need to expose this one and it should be overwriten when the user selects a sorting. If thats not working expose the new sort criteria and call it 'Default' or 'Newest'